# Browse button is missing from media storage

Tags: magento-1.9, product-images, media-images

I am trying to upload a photo into media storage.

but I do not have browse or upload button , it only allows me to see the photos already uploaded to storage.

Answer (score 4):

Open up the **following file:**-

> lib/Varien/File/Uploader.php

Look for **this line:-**

> chmod($destinationFile, 0640);

Replace it with **this line:-**

> chmod($destinationFile, 0644);

Look for **this line:-**

> chmod($destinationFile, 0750);

Replace it with **this line:-**

> chmod($destinationFile, 0755);

**Save the file and now you will see browse button while uploading media.**

Comment: Pranay K: I have the same problem and I only have chmod($destinationFile, 0777); in my Uploader.php (Magento 1.9.1). Shall I change that somehow?

Answer (score 2):

Common issue with Magento 1.x (prior to 1.9.3), main cause is the old flash buttons (yes flash buttons) which were replaced with css buttons so if using older version ensure that files

- uploader.swf
- flex.swf
- uploaderSingle.swf

exist in **skin/adminhtml/default/default/media** directory. If they do, change the browser temporarily or update the flash plugin and restart browser.

Answer (score 0):

Browse buttons use FLASH. So if your browser does not support flash - then they will not appear. Ensure that the app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/media folder exists and that there are 2 files within it.

```
editor.phtml
uploader.phtml
```

Ensure that the skin/adminhtml/default/default/media folder exists and that there are 3 files within it.

```
flex.swf
uploader.swf
uploaderSingle.swf
```

If you have created your own theme (ie Theme: "mytheme" and Package "mypackage") then ensure the above applies for:

```
app/design/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/template/media
skin/adminhtml/mytheme/mypackage/media
```

I hope this helps.